# Getting text from specific entry box in a grid and updating a combobox in that same row

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using a for loop to create my text boxes and comboboxes. I need to be able to change the text in my Text box (entry), then call a function to update the items in the combobox.  Here is the code I am using.

```
def updatelist(updated_Num):
    ...
    ...
    new_list = [{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3}]

options = tk.StringVar(root)
for row, data in enumerate(all_data):
    entry = tk.Text(root, height=1.5, width=15)
    entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event: updateList(updated_Num=entry.get('1.0', 'end-1c')))
    entry.grid(row=row, column=1)

    options = [x for x in data[2]]
    variable.set(options[0])
    combobox = tk.ttk.Combobox(root, value=options, state='readonly')
    combobox.current(0)
    combobox.grid(row=row, column=2)
```

The problem I am having is that it always grabs the text from the LAST entry box created, and it deletes the text from whichever entry box I pressed enter from.

How do I get the text from the specific text box that I entered data into, as well as update the options for the combobox in that row?

edit: This is now working exactly how I want it to. Thanks for the help!

```
def updatelist(updated_Num, row):
    ...
    ...
    new_list = [{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3}]

    options = tk.StringVar(root)
    options = [x for x in new_list]
    variable.set(options[0])
    combobox = tk.ttk.Combobox(root, value=options, state='readonly')
    combobox.current(0)
    combobox.grid(row=row, column=2)

options = tk.StringVar(root)
for row, data in enumerate(all_data):
    entry = tk.Text(root, height=1.5, width=15)
    entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event, entry=entry, row=row: updateList(updated_Num=entry.get('1.0', 'end-1c'), row=row))
    entry.grid(row=row, column=1)

    options = [x for x in data[2]]
    variable.set(options[0])
    combobox = tk.ttk.Combobox(root, value=options, state='readonly')
    combobox.current(0)
    combobox.grid(row=row, column=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you create the `lambda` function in the `for`-loop. It's creating a closure to the value of `entry`, which at the end of the loop is the **last** entry box created. A common way to fix it is to give the lambda a default argument:

```
for row, data in enumerate(all_data):
    entry = tk.Text(root, height=1.5, width=15)
    entry.bind('<Return>', 
               lambda event, entry=entry: updateList(updated_Num=entry.get('1.0', 'end-1c')))
    entry.grid(row=row, column=1)
```

This is a fairly common problem folks have creating `tkinter` widgets in a loop, so your question may get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you, this helped get the correct information to my function, but I still cannot figure out how to update my combobox with the new list returned.  Also, idk why every time I press enter it clears my typed answer. I can always just go back and insert it since I am getting it in my .get, but would be nice to not have to add that.

Comment: @BrianC You can use `combobox.config(values=new_list)` for updating the combobox. For the other part, im not sure, are you deleting the values inside the function?

Comment: @BrianC: There's not enough information in your question to tell you how to fix those other issues. One issue may be the fact that `new_list` is a local variable in the `updatelist()` function. Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: I was able to just copy/paste the options, variable, and combobox lines into the end of my function, and also pass row into the function and now it is working.  Thank you for showing me how to pass info into the function!

Comment: @BrianC: That's good to hear…you're welcome. Just FYI, if all you need to know in the event handler is the widget that caused the event to occur, you can get that from `event.widget` so there wouldn't be a need to pass it separately as shown in my answer. Another user mentioned this, but have since deleted their answer (so you may not be able to see it).

Comment: I cannot see any other responses.  I will try out the event.widget as well! Thanks!

Comment: Example code from deleted question: `entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event: updateList(updated_Num=event.widget.get('1.0', 'end-1c')))`.